# unique() in python doesn't print all values?

Tags: python, pandas

so I am trying to get all unique values in a dataframe.
This is the code

```
for i in df.columns.tolist():
   print(f"{i}")
   print(df[i].unique())
```

This is the result I am getting

```
customerID
['7590-VHVEG' '5575-GNVDE' '3668-QPYBK' ... '4801-JZAZL' '8361-LTMKD' '3186-AJIEK']
gender
['Female' 'Male']
SeniorCitizen
[0 1]
Partner
['Yes' 'No']
Dependents
['No' 'Yes']
tenure
[ 1 34  2 45  8 22 10 28 62 13 16 58 49 25 69 52 71 21 12 30 47 72 17 27
  5 46 11 70 63 43 15 60 18 66  9  3 31 50 64 56  7 42 35 48 29 65 38 68
 32 55 37 36 41  6  4 33 67 23 57 61 14 20 53 40 59 24 44 19 54 51 26  0
 39]
PhoneService
['No' 'Yes']
MultipleLines
['No phone service' 'No' 'Yes']
InternetService
['DSL' 'Fiber optic' 'No']
OnlineSecurity
['No' 'Yes' 'No internet service']
OnlineBackup
['Yes' 'No' 'No internet service']
DeviceProtection
['No' 'Yes' 'No internet service']
TechSupport
['No' 'Yes' 'No internet service']
StreamingTV
['No' 'Yes' 'No internet service']
StreamingMovies
['No' 'Yes' 'No internet service']
Contract
['Month-to-month' 'One year' 'Two year']
PaperlessBilling
['Yes' 'No']
PaymentMethod
['Electronic check' 'Mailed check' 'Bank transfer (automatic)'
 'Credit card (automatic)']
MonthlyCharges
[29.85 56.95 53.85 ... 63.1  44.2  78.7 ]
TotalCharges
['29.85' '1889.5' '108.15' ... '346.45' '306.6' '6844.5']
Churn
['No' 'Yes']
```

Why is It skipping most values in MonthlyCharges and TotalCharges? and how to deal with it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has a setting to not show you all the values if they exceed some length.
So if your dataframe has more than 50 lines I think, it will show you the first 25 then the elipsis (...) then the last few and this is also what is happening here.

You could probably change that by executing the following:

```
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
```

I would anyhow not do that, as if you have a very long dataframe, printing out all those lines might be very time consuming.

Alternatively you could iterate over the unique values and just print them out one by one:

```
for value in df[i].unique():
    print(value)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried It unfortunately It didn't work :(

Comment: @Hajarhajar What's happening now? Still showing only the few lines?

Comment: yes unfortunately! the thing is I want to check if there is any weird value out there  like ' ' or '_' or something like that so that I either remove it or replace it with NaN

Comment: @Hajarhajar But have you tried my suggestion with the loop? This for sure should not omit any values.